# Is C++ still considered as a statically typed language?

Tags: c++, c++11

I used to know that C++ is a statically typed language, but the newer C++ specification introduces a newer syntax `auto` which can determine the variable type by itself. So can C++ still be considered as a statically typed language?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, this does not make C++ a dynamically typed language. [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is just a compile-time type inference method. The resulting code is exactly the same as without `auto` and the type cannot change at run-time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100846/discussion-on-answer-by-sami-kuhmonen-is-c-still-considered-as-a-statically-ty).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks. I tried to do it earlier, but I kept getting some failure message.

Answer (score 4):

C++ is still a statically typed language with the auto type specifier because auto denotes that the type will be inferred by the compiler at compile time. Rather then at run time in dynamically typed languages.

Answer (score 3):

> So can C++ still be considered as a statically typed language?

Yes, because this code snippet still won't compile:

```
auto i = 42;   // 42 is an int -> i is an int
i = "test";    // can't assign a string to an int
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile in any language... interpreted, yes, but compiled no.  However, C++ has the capability of being dynamic.  You could even create a dynamic class, with initializer lists of dynamic objects and get a dynamic result.  I have proof of concept if interested.

Comment: @zackery.fix This has nothing to do with interpreted versus compiled. Those are just implementation strategies, and do not fundamentally affect the semantics of the language.

Comment: @zackery.fix here, a C++ interpreter: https://root.cern.ch/cling. Here, a Lisp compiler: http://www.clisp.org/. That is completely orthogonal with dynamic typing.

Comment: But C++ has the option of changing the languages semantics through metaprogramming.

Comment: That is not the point I am making.  I understand the differences between dynamic and static, and i aware of those projects, but I'm trying to reduce code complexity and minimize the technology foot print.

Comment: Since C++17, it has been possible to simulate dynamic types using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).